# How to escape html within tooltip directive

Tags: angular

I would like to escape the following html text so that the browser can render the text with its carriage returns :

messages.properties

```
tooltip_text=Status:<br/>1- Accepted<br/>2- Rejected
```

mycomponent.component.html

```
<span class="info" tooltip="{{'tooltip_text' | translate }}">i</span>
```

I am aware of the `[innerHTML]` property binding but this would not fit for my use case since the text itself is read by the `tooltip` directive and not displayed raw.

Any idea how may I achieve this please?

Comment: Depends on where the `tooltip` directive comes from. Maybe it supports HTML, maybe not, we can't know

Comment: @Clashsoft it is part of ngx-bootstrap/tooltip

Comment: In that case, its in the docs: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#dynamic-html